# change a tag background color by ID

Tags: javascript, web

HTML is like this:

```
     <div class="header">
<ul>
  <li>
     <a class="abc" id="abc" href="www.testing.com">testing</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My javascript is like this:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var links = document.getElementById("abc");
var a = links.getElementsByTagName("a");
var thisLocationHref = window.location.href;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{

  var tempLink = a[i];      

  if(thisLocationHref === tempLink.href)
  {
      tempLink.style.backgroundColor="red";
  }
  else
  {
      tempLink.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  }
}
```

I cannot remove ID in the a tag because it relates another page.
I know there is something wrong in the code, but cannot figure out where.
Any help is welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: I guess it is just a typo in your example but there is no href present in the a-tag

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot to add the href link... I have added. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `id="abc"` to the `ul` and remove it from the `a` tag, and your code will work.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BgbjD/

From MDN:

> **element.getElementsByTagName**
>
> Returns a list of elements with the given tag name. The subtree
>   underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element
>   itself.

So you have to search the `ul` node.

```
<div class="header">
    <ul id="abc">
        <li> <a class="abc">testing</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your JavaScript doesn't need any changes.

Comment: I add another ID in the ul, and it works. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Not `style.background`, `style.backgroundColor`:

```
var links = document.getElementById("abc");
var a = links.getElementsByTagName("a");
var thisLocationHref = window.location.href;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    var tempLink = a[i];

    if (thisLocationHref === tempLink.href) {
        tempLink.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        tempLink.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but it still doesn't work.Since the class is in the a tag, I think there is something wrong in the loop or inn the getElementsByTagName.